# Reusable Approval Workflow where you choose Approver From an Approver List

Tags: 2013, workflow

I am looking for a Sharepoint Designer 2013 “Reusable Approval Workflow” for “Document Libraries” with Dynamic Approver meaning "The APPROVER" is chosen from an “Approver List” that can have many Approvers listed.

The workflow would be triggered when a New Document needs to be added to the Document Library or an existing document in the Library is modified and needs to be checked-in/released.

I’m fairly new at SharePoint, so would need something with instructions.

Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, I would suggest using the default workflow to get a feel for how this should be structured. In 'Workflow settings' you cans et it to start when a new document is created.

You need somewhere to manage your list of 'Approvers'. An easy way is to make a sharepoint list, which simply contains the names and accounts of these people.

Next, in the workflow go onto the task, assign it to the initiator (the person who creates the document/starts the workflow) and edit task form. I would suggest Nintex as it tends to be easier for simple functionality. Use a 'List Lookup' and point it at your 'Approvers list'. If you save the choice from this to a variable, you can then use that same variable as an 'assignee' for the next stage of approval.

This is the basics, but I may have glossed over something as it's been a while.

If you get stuck let me know, or google each stage and there should be something to help.

Comment: Hi Thomas. Thanks for reply. This is what I've done.

Created an Approvers List (Approvers Prod) in our Main Site. In this list, crteated a new column "Approver" of Type "Person or Group".

Settings:

"Allow selection of:  People Only People and Groups"

"Choose from: All Users".

In Document library "Standards", I added the new "Approver" column.

Comment: When I create a new Reusable WorkFlow using SharePoint Designer 2013, and "Add a Task", I am not able to properly add this Approver list to this new workflow. When I add the new WorkFlow to the "Standards" Library, and add a new document to this library, I DON'T get a pop with the pulldown list of APPROVERS so that I can choose an Approver to approve my document.

Comment: so the task won’t create a pop up, it will create a ‘task’ for a user. Is this case simply to choose an approver. 

In the site contents if you haven’t already create a task list which will store and manage all this. Then, if you have the workflow sorted once you create a document it should create a new task. 

Does that make sense?